# Android 86 over IP (local network) and Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox, android-x86

**What I want to do:**

Boot a VB in one mac with Android x86. Access that emulator over another mac in the same local network *and load applications from the Android Studio I work with on the second mac, to the emulator (first mac)*.

**What I have done:**

Installed the VB successfully. Enable the developer and unknown sources in Android's settings. Fort forward the VB (5555).

**What happens:**

I run `adb connect 192.168.1.4:5555` on the second mac and it connects successfully:

```
List of devices attached 
192.168.1.4:5555    device
```

I open Android studio and select as target the: `innotek_gmbh-virtualbox-192.168.1.4:5555`. In the command line it **stops at**:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: innotek_gmbh-virtualbox-192.168.1.4:5555
```

I go back to the emulator and click `alt+F1` to open the kernel and type `netcfg`. I get:

```
ip6tn10 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0
lo UP 127.0.0.1/8
eth0 UP 10.0.2.15/24
sit0 DOWN 0.0.0.0/0
```

On both Macs I can successfully connect and access the `shell` with `adb connect localhost:5555` or `adb connect 192.168.1.4:5555` as said above.

I can only install the app via `adb install myapp.apk`. 
*Why the app does not load on the targeted device from Android Studio, can I fix this?*

Comment: See if you can find relevant logs from the tools which indicate a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened there but it had to do with the project. Trying another project fixes the problem and Studio can see the VB as a device and of course load the app.